# Postfix Error - RELAY ACCESS DENIED

Tags: postfix

I am quite new mail server configuration. I am trying to send test mail from client (JIRA), this is in different domain, main server is in different domain, and the email i want to send is in different domain. When i send testmail to domain where mail server is configured, there is no problem, but when sending it to external domain, i am getting this error:

```
RELAY ACCESS DENIED
```

I tried with different parameter change as said different forums, but couldn't succeed. could someone please help me ??

Please find the `main.cf` config file :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases  
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_dns_lookups = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname,<hostname>,<hostname.domainname>,localhost,<domain name where i want to send the email>
mydomain = <domainname>
myhostname = <hostname>
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8,99.999.99.999/25
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the sending server to `relayhost`, like this:

```
relayhost = 1.2.3.4
```

Replace `1.2.3.4` with the IP of your sending server.

Afterwards check and reload the config:

```
postconf check
postconf reload
```

And try again.